# Название полигона пишется в кавычках?

Tags: пунктуация

На Грамоте:

Пишется в кавычках: полигон "Кучино". 
Кавычки не требуются: полигон Капустин Яр.

Нужны ли на самом деле кавычки или нет?

Comment: Дубликат авторский: Не тратьте чернила!

Answer (score 0):

Хороший вопрос - я вся как есть изгуглилася...

Разнобой полнейший, но нашлось и нечто обобщающее. Жаль дробить цитату, даю оковалок текста, но всё по делу.

---

---

Анализ вопросов, поступающих в справочные службы русского языка Института русского языка имени В. В. Виноградова РАН и справочно-информационного интернет-портала «Русский язык», позволяет выделить следующие тематико-семантические группы номинативных единиц, вызывающих трудности орфографического оформления:

1. Названия фирм, организаций, учреждений, музыкальных коллективов, спортивных обществ: Внешторгбанк, ВТБ, компании «Транснефть», «Тройка Диалог», АвтоВАЗ, ОАО «Межрегиональный ТранзитТелеком», «Метрогипротранс», ПФК ЦСКА, ОАО «Российские железные дороги» (ОАО «РЖД»), компания Bausch&Lomb, рок-группа Lordi.

***2. Названия общественных мест, объектов недвижимости, географических объектов: аэропорт Шереметьево-2, станция метро «Фили», природный заказник «Тимирязевский», резиденция «Бочаров Ручей», заповедник «Кедровая Падь», полигон «Кура», ТСЖ «Закамск», социальный жилой дом «Митино», микрорайон Куркино.***

3. Названия изделий техники и электроники – производственных марок и самих этих изделий, в том числе названия неоднословные и включающие в себя цифровые обозначения изделий. Это названия автомобилей: «Лада», «Вольво», «Рено-Меган», Toyota Yaris, Daewoo Matiz, ВАЗ-2112, КамАЗ; самолетов и средств покорения космоса: «Руслан», Ту-154, «Боинг-747», шаттл «Дискавери», челнок «Атлантис», стыковочный модуль «Ноуд-2»; военной техники: баллистическая ракета «Тополь», ударный комплекс «Искандер-М»; изделий электронной техники (компьютеры, мобильные телефоны, цифровая фототехника и пр.): Samsung X-100, плеер iPod touch, процессор Intel Core 2 Duo (в основном наименования изделий электронной техники в современных текстах пишут латиницей).
4. Названия, связанные со сферой информационных технологий, в том числе: названия интернет-ресурсов (оформленные кириллицей, латиницей, сочетанием букв двух алфавитов): «Известия.Ру», «Словари.Ру», «Страна.Ru», «Яндекс» (Яndex, Yandex), «Рамблер» (Rambler), названия веб-сервисов: «Яндекс.Фотки», «Яндекс.Словари», WebMoney.
5. Названия лекарств, медицинских препаратов (выступающие как в качестве товарной марки изделия, так и в бытовом употреблении), например: валидол, но-шпа, «Фастум-гель», «Фарингосепт», вакцины «Гриппол», «Ваксигрипп», «Инфлювак», «Агриппал».
6. Названия продовольственных товаров, в том числе алкогольных напитков (выступающие и в качестве бренда, и в бытовом употреблении): вафли «Сливочные», салат «Китайский», соус «Тартар», ликер «Бейлис», вино «Божоле Нуво», кофе «Черная карта».
7. Условные названия видов и сортов сельскохозяйственных культур, овощей, цветов и т. п. – термины агрономии и садоводства: яблоко антоновка, белый налив, «слава победителю», виноград «шардоне», малина «мальборо», тюльпан «черный принц».

В официально действующих в настоящее время «Правилах русской орфографии и пунктуации» 1956 года рекомендации по употреблению кавычек для выделения собственных наименований сформулированы очень коротко и проиллюстрированы ограниченным количеством примеров. В связи с этим для решения вопросов, связанных с орфографическим оформлением наименований, пишущие обращаются к справочным пособиям по правописанию.

**[источник](http://www.gramota.ru/biblio/magazines/gramota/orthografia/28_637)**

---

Таки кавычатся полигоны.

Comment: "Оковалок текста" - это шедевр! Платонов!

Comment: Обижаешь, начальник. Я пишу лучше. Кстати о птицах. ***Окова́лок: "ломоть, кусок", южн., зап., курск., тверск. (Даль). Заимств. через польск. kаwаɫеk, kаwаɫ "кусок" из ср.-нж.-нем. kаvеl "чурка для метания жребия, доля по жребию".***

Comment: Исчо цытата: ***ОКОВА́ЛОК, оковалка, мн. нет, муж.
1. В мясном деле - говядина 1-го сорта, часть туши около таза (спец.).
|| В некоторых местностях - название говядины от шеи около лопатки (спец.).
2. Большой и нескладный кусок чего-нибудь (напр. хлеба; обл.).***